# indentitation in markdown mode

Tags: markdown-mode

I would like to have a double nested list in Makrdown Fill mode. For this I write in my markdown file

```
* item 1
  * item 1.1:
    * item 1.1.1
    * item 1.1.2
```

Now I would like to add an `* item 1.2:` which should be aligned with `* item 1.1:`. However, emacs allows me, using tab, just the two positions, either:

```
* item 1
  * item 1.1:
    * item 1.1.1
    * item 1.1.2
    * item 1.2
```

or

```
* item 1
  * item 1.1:
    * item 1.1.1
    * item 1.1.2
* item 1.2
```

I would need to use spaces, but that doesn't make sense in my opinion. Why is emacs not allowing me to align them properly, i.e. leave the right indentation out?

Comment: Emacs can do better, but by default markdown-mode doesn't. It uses the function indent-relative, which provides very simplistic indentation. Basically, it looks at the previous line and offers you any plausible tab stops it sees there. It doesn't consider any further context or language-specific details. Which means you're left to manually indent `* item 1.2` in your example. To fix this will require providing markdown-mode with a more intelligent indentation function, or borrowing something from another mode. you can contact the maintainers directly: https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode

Comment: @Tyler `markdown-mode` no longer uses `indent-relative`, but rather a customizable indentation function (`markdown-indent-line`, by default) which calculates indentation in context.  I do see that `indent-relative` is mentioned in a docstring, so apologies for that. It's out of date and I'll update it.

Comment: @user8 The issue is that your list is ambiguous: [different processors give three different answers](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=*+item+1%0A++*+item+1.1%3A%0A++++*+item+1.1.1%0A++++*+item+1.1.2). Markdown.pl sees only two list levels, because it specifies that nested lists should be indented by four spaces. For lists `markdown-mode` follows Markdown.pl, so if you indent lists by four spaces, or if you let `markdown-mode` handle the indentation for you (with `C-u` or `C-u C-u` prefixes) from the start, then it will work out as expected.